# Tracing network RJ45 / RJ11 cable from user desk to patch panel backend

Tags: patch-panel

I am new to these kind of work and I don't have much experience in network tracing. I have receive a new task which I was told to trace all patch cable of RJ45/RJ11 from the phone panel @ user desk to patch panel backend. Then I was told to produce a new updated layout of the patch panel.

There's a lot of phones in that office from ground floor to 2nd floor. May I hear your advice on how to do trace this patch cable?

thanks.

Comment: This is dredge work done with a fluke tester. Don't have time to write up a longer response, but basically 1. Plug module into socket at desk, 2. Run master end over the patch panel until it beeps.

Comment: you poor bugger....     that's going to keep you bored out of your brain for a very long time

Answer (score 5):

This task is going to be extremely tedious.

The best way to do it is to get a tone generator tool.  Plug the tone generator into each user jack and then go to the patch panel and see which jack the tone is in with the wand; then, check the connection to see you have the right jack, and it's traced.

The other thing to do is make a loopback cable that connects the centre two pins of the jack.  Those pins are almost always straight through in the cable, but you can connect the two pins outside of that together also if you want.  Then, test which jack on the patch panel has the centre two pins connected (you can make another cable that just breaks the jack out into bare wires for this).

There are lots and lots of commercially produced tools available at pretty much any hardware store for various prices that can do anything from just help you trace cables to determining how long those cables are and whether they are up to spec.  Such a thing (I won't recommend any particular one) will make this task much easier.

While doing any of these things it's strongly advised that you ensure nothing else is connected on the other end of the cable (such as a switch, or a PoE insert, or a phone line) to avoid breaking anything.

Comment: Thanks,

 like what you have said 
"While doing any of these things it's strongly advised that you ensure nothing else is connected on the other end of the cable (such as a switch, or a PoE insert, or a phone line) to avoid breaking anything."

Does it mean if I use a tone tester tool....one end is connected to the tone tester and the other end must be unplugged? :O

Which means that there will be a downtime for all the telephone lines?

Comment: Also, LABEL THE END POINTS once you identify them. My preference is to assign each patch panel a letter (eg, 'A') then each end-point can be labelled as a concatenation of the patch panel letter and the port number (1 to 24 or however many ports the patch panel has). eg, "A16". I've seen people try to just use sequential numbers across all patch panels (ie, port 1 on the second patch panel is "25") and that just ends up in a horrible mess.

Comment: Yes, you should label the endpoints according to both panel and jack.  Additionally, you should not trace cables while they are in use for something, so yes, this might mean some downtime.  It would be very difficult to connect the cable to your test tool when it is already connected to equipment, and the equipment (phone lines, network cards, etc.) isn't usually designed to have test tools connected on the other end.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a Network locator tool, commonly called fox and hound

This is a great entry level model

[http://www.tigerdirect.com](http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/category/category_slc.asp?MfrId=0&CatId=1797)

If you want to save yourself some headaches, get a model that comes with multiple ends.

[http://www.mcmelectronics.com](http://www.mcmelectronics.com/product/DISTRIBUTED-BY-MCM-TCT-2690KT-/22-16374)

With your tool, plug one end into a network cable at the user's desk, then plug the other end of your tool into a cable in the patch panel.  Repeat until you get a tone or a light on the fox and hound.